# How does Pokèmon Go uses custom Google map using Google Map API?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-api, native

I am not able to find anywhere on Google API document that its map can be customized *(i know it can be customized on web only)* but can see on the **Pokèmon Go** app that it uses Google API to show custom map.

Reference for Pokèmon Go uses google map: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s71t1/suggestion_download_city_map_as_a_way_to_decrease/

Anyone able to figure out this approach?

Custom map i means the map below with green color and blue sky:
[image]

Comment: Tile Overlays could be an option: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay

Comment: The Pokemon Go maps was designed using mapbox studio sdk.

Comment: @HarshPatel do you have a source on that?

Answer (score 47):

I don't know how Pokémon GO does it, but you can get a really nice looking effect with some layout tricks. I'm using a sky image and I'm covering the sky image and the map with a gradient view (to simulate the horizon) and the map with a semitransparent green view.

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/sky"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientsky"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="mypackage.MapsActivity"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2200ff00"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientmap"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**gradientsky.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**gradientmap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**MapsActivity.java** (trivial, but I'm adding it so the example is complete)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(39.87266,-4.028275))
                .zoom(18)
                .tilt(67.5f)
                .bearing(314)
                .build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Another approach could be using a TileOverlay to show a custom map. You can find more info about Tile Overlays [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay).

To improve the example, you may want to add some parallax effect to the sky so it moves when the map rotates.

Comment: You made my day :D

Comment: Awesome, can you submit a gist with this example please?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

**[Wikipedia arcticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niantic,_Inc.) to the creator of Pokèmon Go:**

> Niantic, Inc. is a software development company best known for
>   developing the augmented reality mobile games Ingress and Pokémon Go.
>   It was formed by Keyhole, Inc. founder John Hanke in 2010 as Niantic
>   Labs, an internal startup at **Google**.

As you can see, Niantic was an internal startup at Google. Although both companies went their separate way, Google still invests in Niantic. So I think that Niantic has some possibilities, that aren't available for us. As you said, I neither found a way in the Google Maps docs for Android.

I'm not exactly sure if this is true, it's just a guess.