# How to create custom google maps style in Android app (Java)

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to develop an Android application that contains a customized map ( I guess I have to use the Google API ) .

What I would do is to create an interactive map as that of "Ingress" or "Pokemon Go" , I wondered if this could be done simply by superimposing a custom layout to the existing one or if there are alternative methods.

Currently I have only found this document but refers to the web version , there is a specific way to Android or do I create a webview ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/styling-the-base-map

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323724/how-does-pok%c3%a8mon-go-uses-custom-google-map-using-google-map-api/38324961

Comment: I have a [sample app on GitHub](https://github.com/PPartisan/FantasyMapTutorial/tree/master/app/src/main) that shows how to create custom tiles to create a "Fantasy Map" with Google Maps API - is that the kind of thing your after? (This creates a "top-down" 2D map though, not the perspective effect seen in Pokemon Go)

Comment: Ingress uses libdgx and pokemon uses Unity, so you can't just use google maps to do the same but you can use custom tiles to simplify the problem and do what PPartisan told

Comment: Google announced that custom map styles are now available for Android and iOS after September 2016 release. Please have a look at this blog post: https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylize map with google map api2 for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722418/stylize-map-with-google-map-api2-for-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Google Maps styles available for [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) too.