# Add 3D object to map and pan around it

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, mapbox

I am trying to make a Pokemon GO clone (educational work) and I know there are several possible ways to style the Google Maps using [layout tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324961/798314) or [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/location-based-game-map/). My biggest challenge is to add a 3d object/model to the map and using gestures to zoom and pan around my character.

---

[image: Example of a 3D model on map and panning]

Somehow the camera should be fixed to the object (marker?) and panning/zooming should be disabled on the map but the gestures should rotate the camera around the character. I was wondering if someone can shoot me in the right direction on how to implement such feature using the native Android SDK and Google Maps/MapBox

Since Pokemon GO is **not** using Google Maps, I am wondering how they implemented their own map stuff, but this is outside the scope of this question.

(I am not looking for a paid solution such as [here.com](https://developer.here.com/) or [nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/nutiteq-sdk/overview/) )

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox Android SDK doesn't currently support 3D object, In this use case, i'd recommend using Mapbox alongside Unity instead which is made for these purposes. Here's a [great blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-unity/) showing off how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not looking to create this application in Unity. Do you have an idea if 3d support is coming soon to the MapBox Android SDK? I am wondering if I can access the OpenGL thread through MapBox and draw the model on OpenGL

Comment: were you able  to implement this?