# Add 3D object to map pan around it and animate it

Tags: android, mapbox-android

This question has been previously raised, but with a gap of 7 years, I am resurfacing it:

[Add 3D object to map and pan around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974829/add-3d-object-to-map-and-pan-around-it)

The core inquiry remains unchanged, but I'm also curious about the feasibility of utilizing Mapbox for Android not only to position a 3D character and enable camera rotation around it but also to animate said character. By animation, I mean implementing movements such as Idle, walking, running.

So far, I've been using the Mapbox Unity SDK, but for the project I'm attempting to undertake, I find myself compelled to use Android Studio.